# Relation between magnitudes of electric field and magnetic field in free space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation

[image: Snapshot of the derivation from my textbook]

I understand the derivation till the partial derivative part. After that there comes a line where it makes a substitution in the relation which says that partial derivative of electric field w.r.t position is equal to the negative of partial derivative of magnetic field w.r.t time.

Where did this relation come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the $z$-component of one of Maxwell‘s equations, namely

$$\nabla\times\mathbf E=-\frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t},$$

which expresses Faraday’s law of induction.